# What does this vite error mean? SyntaxError: Unexpected token (6:180) at Object.pp$4.raise

Tags: svelte, sapper, vite, sveltekit

I am upgrading my Sapper application to SvelteKit. I can run npm run dev fine and it starts my application on localhost:3000. When I browse to that URL, I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (6:180)
at Object.pp$4.raise (../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-66eb515d.js:35308:13)
at Object.pp.unexpected (../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-66eb515d.js:32999:8)
at Object.pp.expect (../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-66eb515d.js:32993:26)
at Object.pp$3.parseObj (../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-66eb515d.js:34944:12)
at Object.pp$3.parseExprAtom (../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-66eb515d.js:34683:17)
at Object.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-66eb515d.js:34509:19)
at Object.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-66eb515d.js:34486:17)
at Object.parseMaybeUnary (../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-66eb515d.js:43031:29)
at Object.pp$3.parseExprOps (../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-66eb515d.js:34421:19)
at Object.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (../node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-66eb515d.js:34404:19)
```

I can't figure out the point this error is being raised. Can anyone suggest a place to look?

My svelte.config.cjs is

```
const node = require('@sveltejs/adapter-node');

module.exports = {
    kit: {
        // By default, `npm run build` will create a standard Node app.
        // You can create optimized builds for different platforms by
        // specifying a different adapter
        adapter: node(),

    // hydrate the <div id="svelte"> element in src/app.html
    target: '#svelte',

    vite: {
        ssr: {
            noExternal: ['node-fetch']
        }
    }
}
};
```

My package.json includes the follows

```
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^1.0.0-next.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@sveltejs/kit": "next",
    "vite": "^2.1.5",
    "@sveltejs/adapter-node": "next",
    "svelte": "^3.35.0",
    "svelte-flex": "^1.2.2",
    "svelte-simple-modal": "^0.9.0"
  }
```

Comment: Also tried with "vite": "^2.1.0",

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this error myself. I found more specifics on the error when I ran **npm run build** instead of **npm run dev**. This pointed out the error was in        the file $error.svelte.

Since I didn't need a custom error, I deleted that page and now I am able to access my site on localhost:3000.

Although I didn't get to the bottom of this I am marking this correct as it revealed the location of the error.

Comment: Ummm, deleting the problem page may have worked in your specific case, but it's hardly a solution!

Answer (score 0):

The error page has changed a little bit, more info here:
https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#layouts-error-pages